# Strange implicit scala compile error

Tags: scala

I have this method defined in an abstract class:

```
abstract class RichTable[T](name: String) extends Table[T](name) {
    def insert(model : T) = Database { implicit db: Session =>
    *.insert(model.copy(id = getNextId(classOf[T].getSimpleName())))
  }
  //other methods which are fine
}
```

and it (`model.copy`) says:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[T]
```

I simply don't know how to solve this issue. I am a scala beginner and I am simply stuck with this. Can anybody give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Evidence parameter is the curried implicit parameter of function, like in `model.copy(id)(implicit typeMapper)`. You need to declare `implicit val typeMapper: scala.slick.lifted.TypeMapper[T] = something`. Search F3 in a source of `model.copy`.

**EDIT**

Not quite right, changing `def insert(model: T) to def insert[T: ClassManifest](model: T)` should do the trick. Why?

Inside your function, you use `classOf[T]`, but actual type of T gets erased in runtime, and its not clear on which class `getSimpleName()` should be invoked. So you should declare a type parameter with `ClassManifest` bound, and an implicit parameter of appropriate type should be added automatically `[T](model: T)(implicit evidence$1: ClassManifest[T])`